# Networkx not coloring edges correctly by attribute

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, networkx, graph-coloring

I am trying to depict a transport network in networkx and I have been doing good till now, but the problem is the following:
I have loaded an edgelist from a txt file, which is in the following form:

```
61  1
54  79
66  134
68  57
```

etc. Also, in order to plot network nodes in the correct position, I have loaded and added to the Graph a txt with nodes coordinates which is in the following form:

```
1   478947.434  4204495.502
2   478909.145  4204244.629
3   479065.936  4204709.003
4   478880.827  4204297.676
5   478993.409  4204167.957
```

After that, I run the following script and my network is correctly depicted, position-wise.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as py
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Book, Range

pos={}
with open(r'C:\Users\alexl\Documents\new_python\nodes_coordinates.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        node, x, y = line.split()
        pos[node] = float(x), float(y)

print(pos)
network0 = nx.read_edgelist(r'C:\Users\alexl\Documents\new_python\init_edgelist.txt', create_using = nx.OrderedDiGraph)

nx.draw(network0, pos = pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = G, edge_cmap = plt.cm.Reds, connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0.1')
         

plt.show()
```

Now, what I want is to correctly assign "weights" to every edge, and color it by this attribute. For every edge there are 3 possible outcomes, 0, 1 and 2, so I want 3 different colours, for example, red for 0, green for 1 and blue for 2. What I have is a Python dictionary like this:

```
{0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 1.0,...
```

etc.The first value (1.0) corresponds to the first edge of edgelist above, the second (1.0) to the second, etc. But I see networkx does not understand this and does not colorize correctly my network. I converted dictionary to list and did the following:

```
var1 = G.values()
list1 = list(var1)
col = []
for n in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[n] == 0:
        col.append('b')
    elif list1[n] == 1:
        #col.append('r')
    else:
        #col.append('g') 
nx.draw(network0, pos = pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = col, edge_cmap = plt.cm.Reds, connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0.1')
```

I checked the result but the correspondence is not the correct one. I think that, if there are 32 '0's in the list, it colors 32 edges with the color I assigned to it, but not the correct ones. (But every time I run it the same 32 edges are colored this way, so it's probably not random.) I wonder what's incorrect. I tried it also as a dictionary (not converting to list), but then colors are more than 3 actually, I don;t know why.
Should I try to add these values (0, 1, 1, 2 etc) to the edgelist.txt in order the assignment to be done correctly?

Comment: What is the variable `G`?

Comment: G is a dictionary like this: `{0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 1.0,...`. And what I want is to assign one-on-one the dictionary values in the edges. There are as many dictionary "items" as edges in the edgelist, and i want the first value (1.0) to be assigned to the first edge of the edgelist while coloring. And also, to be colored accordingly to the dictionary value (0.0, 1.0 or 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the edges passed to the drawing functions are important.
You need to make sure that your `edge_color` list(`col`) is in the same order as `network0.edges`, which it isn't.

This is happening because `network0.edges` is not in the same order as your `init_edgelist.txt` file, as you were probably assuming.

To check this try printing `network0.edges` and compare.

### Solution

Instead I would suggest adding edge weights with the pretended color to the edge while creating `network0`, like so:

```
G = {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 1.0}
list1 = list(G.values())
col = []
for n in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[n] == 0:
        col.append('b')
    elif list1[n] == 1:
        col.append('r')
    else:
        col.append('g') 


network0 = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
i = 0
with open(r'init_edgelist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        n1, n2 = line.split()
        network0.add_edge(n1, n2, color = col[i])
        i += 1
```

Then you just need to extract the colors and draw:

```
colors = [network0[u][v]['color'] for u,v in network0.edges()]

nx.draw(network0, pos = pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = colors, edge_cmap = plt.cm.Reds, connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.1')
```

#### *full code*:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as py
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Book, Range

pos={}
with open(r'nodes_coordinates.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        node, x, y = line.split()
        pos[node] = float(x), float(y)

#print(pos)

G = {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 1.0}
list1 = list(G.values())
col=[]
for n in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[n] == 0:
        col.append('b')
    elif list1[n] == 1:
        col.append('r')
    else:
        col.append('g') 

network0 = nx.OrderedDiGraph()

i = 0
with open(r'init_edgelist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        n1, n2 = line.split()
        network0.add_edge(n1,n2, color=col[i])
        i += 1

#print(network0.edges())

colors = [network0[u][v]['color'] for u,v in network0.edges()]

nx.draw(network0,pos=pos,with_labels=True,edge_color=colors,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds, connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.1')
```

Comment: Check this last edit, the other one had a small error in the code

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for trying to solve my problem. I wrote this last script, but does not return the edges correctly, unfortunately... The first 5 lines of initial_edgelist.txt are: `61 1
54 79
66 134
68 57
65 86`. While when I print network0.edges, I see this: `('61', '1'), ('61', '69'), ('61', '60'), ('1', '128'), ('1', '75')`. I know that probably this representation would be better, as it first has all edges starting with 61, after that all edges starting with 1, etc. But I don't want this. I really appreciate that you answered my question! I am quite new to networkx.

Comment: But have you checked if the edges have the colors you pretended?

Comment: I mean this answer was meant to answer your question, I just gave you the problem behind your code

Comment: My pleasure! Also, I edited my answer: I get why you thought my answer would fix the ordering of network0.edges(), but it was just intended to color the edges exactly has you wanted.

Comment: Ehm, MY fault I did not try it! Your code does what i wanted to do! Thank you very much.