# Networkx not giving correct colors based on wegiths from data frame

Tags: graph, networkx, edges

I am trying to create graphs of conflicts and alliances between drug trafficking organizations. I want conflicts to be graphed as red edges, and alliances to be graphed as blue edges. I gave each relationship a weight so that Networkx could give each relationship a different color. This is the edgelist I have:

But the colors shown are inconsistent with the weights. I have tried different things but nothing seems to work. This is my code:

---

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv("2004N.csv")
df

    Source  Target  Weight
0   Gulf Cartel     Sinaloa Cartel  -1
1   Tijuana Cartel  Sinaloa Cartel  -1
2   Gulf Cartel     Juarez Cartel   1
3   Tijuana Cartel  Gulf Cartel     1
4   Tijuana Cartel  Juarez Cartel   1
5   Juarez Cartel   Sinaloa Cartel  -1

 

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source', 'Target', edge_attr="Weight")

plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,8))

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500, edge_color=df['Weight'], width=5.0)
```

---

This is the image I get:

[Color of edges are not consistent with weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZZ9W.png)

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Networkx not coloring edges correctly by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422824/networkx-not-coloring-edges-correctly-by-attribute)

Comment: Thank you Paul! I will give this a try. I think It could work. Thank you!